# Get touch in webView

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I have add `UIWebView`  on `UIViewController`then add one another `UIViewController` on same `ViewController` then i want get touch on `UIwebView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an `UIWebView` as a child of `UIViewController`'s view. The solution that worked for me (for tab gesture) is this:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(onDoubleTap:)];
tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
tap.delegate = self;

[self.webView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

My `UIViewController` is implementing the following method from the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` protocol (just retunning YES):

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add Gesture

First set delegate    in.h file

```
 -(void)ViewDidLoad
   {
          UITapGestureRecognizer   *gesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
       initWithTarget:self action:@selector(HandleGesture:)];
         gesture.delegate=self;
          gesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
         [YourWebview addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
    }
   -(void)HandleGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
    {
        if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
        {

        }
        if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
        {
                    // You can write here any action
        }
    }
    - (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
      // test if our control subview is on-screen
        if ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIWebView class]]) {
             // You can handle any thing
            return YES;
         }return NO; // handle the touch
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

For recognizing the touch events  of `UIWebview`,`UIScrollview`  you can use Gestures.don't forgot to add `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` in .h file.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *single = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(oneTap)];
    single.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    single.delegate = self;
    [webview addGestureRecognizer:single];

-(void)oneTap{
    NSLog(@"single");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the touch from a gesture recognizer is to the view, not page-based.  So if you want your app to respond to a particular item on your web page, no matter where it's scrolled or zoomed to, you'd be better off using URL schemes to send a signal to your app.